# Regular Expression of alternative 0's and 1's?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, regular-expressions, formal-systems

Let $L$ be the language of $0$'s and $1$'s in alternate positions, where
$$
L = \{ \epsilon, 0, 1, 01, 10, 01010,\ldots\}.
$$

Is $(0)*$ + $(1)*$ a valid regular expression that represents this language? Why not?

Comment: WHat do you mean by $+$ in the regular expression? Union?

Comment: yes, It's a union.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression $0^*+1^*$ denotes the union of $0^*$ and $1^*$. The first one denotes the set of words  $\{\epsilon,0,00,000,0000,\dots\}$ and $1^*$ denotes $\{\epsilon,1,11,111,1111,\dots\}$. The expression does not do what you want.

What you want is, for example, $(01)^*+(10)^*+(01)^*0+(10)^*1$. Can you see why this works?

Comment: I got it, Thanks.

Comment: Just to be sure can you please elaborate more on how we can get an epsilon,0 or 1 from your suggested regular expression?

Comment: $\epsilon$ is an element of $(01)^*$, and then $0$ is an element of $(01)^*0$.

Comment: You should probably review the definition of the star :-)

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression only recognize $01.01.01...$ is one or more occurrences of $01$ and followed by a zero is denoted by $(01)+0$.

The regular expression only recognize $10.10.10...$ is one or more occurrences of $10$ and followed by an one is denoted by $(10)+1$.

Thus, regular expression to recognize alternative $0$ and $1$ is

$$r=(01)+0 | (10)+1.$$

Comment: you missed the `ϵ` here